# AdMob mediation (Android and iOS) : how to force a network to test it?

Tags: android, ios, admob, mopub, inmobi

I am implementing AdMob mediation with several third party networks. I would like to test that the mediation with each of these networks is well implemented (ads well displayed).

I would like to force the display of an ad from a defined network to test its implementation, and then switch quickly to another network.

One way to do that should be to change the bids in the AdMob mediation interface. For example put 100$ on the network I want to test and 0.1 $ on the other ones.

But the problem is it seems that there is some delay before the changes are taken into account and even after a long delay, it seems that I do not have 100% of ads from the network at 100$.

How can I force a network (any test mode ?) in a manner that I will have immediately ads from this networks on 100% of the requests ? It could be test ads from this network.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I am also looking for such solution

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution... :(

Answer (score 1):

Most of the third part ad networks don't have a test mode via AdMob mediation.

The only way I have found so far is via the
AdMob dashboard->Monetize->'Your App's Mediation page'.
In that page when you click on the ad sources:

[image]

It will show you an edit option, from where you can pause/enable ads from individual ad networks:
[image]

I do share your pain of the delay it takes for those dashboard changes to propagate to the actual test device.

Hope this was of some help.

Kind regards,
Mukund Agarwal